# SortBy not Supported by WSO2IS SCIM 2.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using the WSO2IS SCIM2 API to get a list of users, but it seems that the api doesn't support the sorting.

Is there another way to sort the results? Will this feature be available in next versions?
Thanks

When calling GET /scim2/Users?count=10&startIndex=0&sortBy=userName
I receive the following response:
[Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfEcx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting by username is not supported in WSO2 IS at the moment.
Refer: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/4362

As per this [comment](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/4362#issuecomment-890781216), if the feature is added to the product will most probably be supported for single-user stores having RDBMS semantics.